# Compact convergence of polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

I Want to prove that there is no Sequence of complex polynomial that converges to $f(z)=\frac{1}{z} $ on $D=\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. 
Suppose there is a Sequence of complex polynomial converging compact on D. What Happens to this Sequence at $0$? I am searching for an Argument that the sequence of polynomials converges there too. Or is this false? 
One could follow that since all polynomial are entire functions the limit $f$ is entire too.  It isn't so we have the contradiction. 
Though I know other ways to prove this I wanted to know if one can do it this way too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the sequence of polynomials would then converge too in $0$. If $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the given sequence then $p_n(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}p_n(e^{it})\mathrm dt$. By uniform convergence on $S^1$ and Lebesgue's theorem the integrals converge to $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\mathrm dt = 0$

Comment: nice! thank you, finished my answer at the same moment.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $p_n$ are holomorhic polynomials such that $p_n(z) \to 1/z$ uniformly on the unit circle. Then by uniform convergence and Cauchy's theorem,

$$0 = \int_{|z|=1}p_n(z)\,dz \to \int_{|z|=1}(1/z)\,dz = 2\pi i,$$

contradiction. So there is no such sequence.